# How can I highlight or change the color of the pipe character in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I thought maybe the Highlight extension might work (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fabiospampinato.vscode-highlight), but I can't figure out how to create the regular expression.

```
"highlight.regexes": {
        "(\\|)": [
            {
                "color":"red"
            }
        ]

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  "highlight.regexes": {

    "([^|]*)(\\|)":  {
      "regexFlags": "gi",
      // "filterLanguageRegex": "markdown",
      "decorations": [
        {},
        {
          "color": "red",
        },
      ]
    }
  }
```

From the readme:

> All characters of the matched string must be wrapped in a capturing
>   group.

Your `(\\|)` would only work if the pipe was the first character on the line.

And sometimes a reload is required to get the highlighting to work properly.